# Visual Studio 2015 seems to be hiding from me?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2015 Community.

It's a bit difficult to explain, but here goes.

It seems like Visual Studio is not updating the window when I e.g. Open a project, tries to write in command line, open a file.. or do anything. But a soon as I manually resize the window of Visual Studio, all the things I have pressed or typed appears.

I have Visual Studio installed on two computers. At first it was all fine and dandy on my laptop, everything worked as it should.
Then the problem started on my desktop computer, so I decided to go back to my laptop, but surprise!  Now my laptop had been cursed with the same problem! (They use the same user in Visual Studio).

I have tried to re-install VS, repair VS and delete the cache folder inside "App Data"-folder, but no luck.

It seems like Visual Studio works fine, but it just won't show me. (Unless I resize the window)

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: did you try from menu window... reset window layout ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that aswell :(

Comment: maybe you are using 2 screens, otherwise it is really strange

Comment: I have tried with one and two screens connected - Before I had the problem, I worked perfectly fine with two screens.

Comment: Do you have any of the same VS Extensions installed on both machines?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem!

It was the voice communication app called "Mumble" that created all the fuss!

Mumble has a feature called "Overlay" - That feature makes VS go crazy, apparently!

Turning it off, makes all of my troubles go away.

Thank you all for the input anyways.